# How to dynamically pass parameters to IN(1,2,3 ....N) Clause in SQL

Tags: ssis

I need to pass parameters to

```
Delete dbo.TableABC Where Id in (Here i need to pass list of Id dynamically)
```

Note: I am working with SSIS

Comment: How do you expect to generate this list? Would it be the result of a data flow? How many row(s) do you expect to delete per run? I assume the table is on SQL Server? What version (2005/2008/2008R2/012)?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is to have a Script Task generate the SQL you need (e.g. using a technique similar to the one described [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2007/07/22/ssis-design-pattern-dynamic-sql.aspx)) and putting that in a variable that is accessible in the rest of your package.

I'm assuming that you're going to use an Execute SQL task to execute your `Delete` - one of the things you can do is have the Execute SQL task run SQL stored in a variable (it should be something like setting the `SQLSourceType` to `Variable`) and providing the details of the variable which was populated by your Script Task.